# Japanese characters screwing up lxml parsing

Tags: python, lxml

How would I do the following in lxml?

```
runtime_text = node.xpath("//dl/dt[text()=u'Runtime:' or text()=u'Laufzeit:' or text()=u'再生時間：']/following-sibling::dd")[0].text.strip()
```

It works fine without the Kanji, but as soon as that line is added in, it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1498, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:52102)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 295, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:151816)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1393, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:27087)
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

Comment: `runtime_text = node.xpath(u"//dl/dt[text()='Runtime:' or text()='Laufzeit:' or text()='再生時間：']/following-sibling::dd")[0].text.strip()` maybe? lxml probably doesn't understand *python*'s unicode literals

Comment: @AnthonySottile: Given that `lxml` is written in C... yeah, probably :D

Comment: I'll convert to an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you want:

`runtime_text = node.xpath(u"//dl/dt[text()='Runtime:' or text()='Laufzeit:' or text()='再生時間：']/following-sibling::dd")[0].text.strip()`

lxml probably doesn't understand *python*'s unicode literals

Comment: The `xpath()` method supports expressions in XPath syntax.  And the xpath syntax is separate from python. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath